# Passing data to variables from other Javascript files

Tags: javascript, modernizr

I'm working on a project that is driving me crazy, I've searched through the articles here on the site but I've not been able to get it into my head how to make this work.

I am using a Modernizr.js file to check for Geolocation and localStorage, the localStorage piece is working fine as well as finding the latitude, longitude and creating a map with the geolocation file. The issue I'm having is passing the latitude and longitude values back to the main js file so that I can pass those values (along with the form data entered on the page) into a constructor function.

I don't know if it is the order of my statements or if I am passing the data incorrectly, I've been battling this for a while now and have only succeeded in confusing myself more. If anyone can help to clarify this for me I would greatly appreciate it.

I am including all files for this project, again am only stuck on passing the values for the latitude and longitude back from the geolocation.js file.

HTML File:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JavaScript, Ajax and JSON: To Do List</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="toDoL14O2.css">
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
  <script src="Modernizr.js"></script>  
  <script>

    Modernizr.load([
       "toDoL14O2.js",
     {
      test: Modernizr.geolocation,
      yep: "L14O2geolocation.js",  
      nope: "L14O2noGeolocation.js"
     },
     {
      test: Modernizr.localstorage,
      yep: "L14O2localStorage.js",
      nope: "L14O2noLocalStorage.js",
      complete: function() {
       init();
     }
    }
   ]);
 </script>           
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <h1>My To Do List</h1>
  <ul id="todoList">
  </ul>

  <!-- display the map//-->
  <div id="mapDiv">
   <h1>Where To Do It</h1>
   <div id="map">
  </div>
 </div>

<!--  display the search results //-->
  <div id="searchResults">
  <h2>Results</h2>
   <ul id="searchResultsList">
   </ul>
  </div>

<form>
 <!--  display the search input //-->
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Search to do items</legend>
   <div class="tableContainer">
   <div class="tableRow">
    <label for="searchTerm">Search: </label>
        <input type="text" id="searchTerm" size="35"
               placeholder="search term">
   </div>
  <div class="tableRow">
    <label for="searchButton"></label>
    <input type="button" id="searchButton" value="Search">
  </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
 <legend>Add a new to do item</legend>
 <div class="tableContainer">
 <div class="tableRow">
    <label for="task">Task: </label>
        <input type="text" id="task" size="35" placeholder="get milk">
 </div>
 <div class="tableRow">
    <label for="who">Who should do it: </label>
        <input type="text" id="who" placeholder="Scott">
 </div>
 <div class="tableRow">
            <label for="dueDate">Due Date:  </label>
        <input type="date" id="dueDate" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
 </div>
 <div class="tableRow">
    <label for="submit"></label>
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit">
 </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

toDo JavaScript File:

```
function Todo(id, task, who, dueDate, days, lat, lon) {
  this.id = id;
  this.task = task;
  this.who = who;
  this.dueDate = dueDate;
  this.done = false;
  this.days = days;
  this.lat = lat;
  this.lon = lon;
}

var todos = new Array();

var lat;
var lon;
console.log("Before Onload: " + lat + ", " + lon);

window.onload = init;
function init() {
 var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
 submitButton.onclick = getFormData;

 // get the search term and call the click handler
 var searchButton = document.getElementById("searchButton");
 searchButton.onclick = searchTodos;

 getTodoItems();
}

function getTodoItems() {
  if (localStorage) {
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        var key = localStorage.key(i);
        if (key.substring(0, 4) == "todo") {
            var item = localStorage.getItem(key);
            var todoItem = JSON.parse(item);
            todos.push(todoItem);
        }
    }
   addTodosToPage();
  }
  else {
    console.log("Error: you don't have localStorage!");
  }
}

function addTodosToPage() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("todoList");
  var listFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
   for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
    var todoItem = todos[i];
    var li = createNewTodo(todoItem);
    listFragment.appendChild(li);
   }
  ul.appendChild(listFragment);
}

function addTodoToPage(todoItem) {
  var ul = document.getElementById("todoList");
  var li = createNewTodo(todoItem);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  document.forms[0].reset();
}

function createNewTodo(todoItem) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.setAttribute("id", todoItem.id);

  var spanTodo = document.createElement("span");
  spanTodo.innerHTML =
    todoItem.who + " needs to " + todoItem.task + " by " +   
     todoItem.dueDate + " at Lat: " + todoItem.lat + "  & Lon: " +  
      todoItem.lon + "Task has " + todoItem.days + " days until due";

   var spanDone = document.createElement("span");
    if (!todoItem.done) {
     spanDone.setAttribute("class", "notDone");
     spanDone.innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
     else {
      spanDone.setAttribute("class", "done");
      spanDone.innerHTML = "&nbsp;&#10004;&nbsp;";
    }

// add the click handler to update the done state
  spanDone.onclick = updateDone;

// add the delete link
  var spanDelete = document.createElement("span");
  spanDelete.setAttribute("class", "delete");
  spanDelete.innerHTML = "&nbsp;&#10007;&nbsp;";

// add the click handler to delete
  spanDelete.onclick = deleteItem;

  li.appendChild(spanDone);
  li.appendChild(spanTodo);
  li.appendChild(spanDelete);

  return li;
}

function getFormData() {
  var task = document.getElementById("task").value;
   if (checkInputText(task, "Please enter a task")) return;

   var who = document.getElementById("who").value;
   if (checkInputText(who, "Please enter a person to do the task"))  
     return;

   var date = document.getElementById("dueDate").value;
    if (checkInputText(date, "Please enter a due date")) return;

// later, process date here
//send date input to checkDate function, will validate correct format 
//and return value for how many days until due or how many days overdue.
 checkDate(date);
   var numOfDays;
   calculateDays(date);

   var id = (new Date()).getTime();

//The findLocation function will call either the L14O2geolocation.js or 
//the L14O2noGeolocation.js files, using the Modernizr.js file to check 
//to see if geolocation is enabled, if so will display map where to do
//item is to be done and if not will return message no geolocation is 
//enbled.

//var lat;
//var lon;

findLocation(lat, lon);

  console.log("Return lat and long! " + lat + ", " + lon);

  var todoItem = new Todo(id, task, who, date, lat, lon);
  todos.push(todoItem);
  addTodoToPage(todoItem);
  saveToDoItem(todoItem);

// hide search results
  hideSearchResults();
}

function checkInputText(value, msg) {
  if (value == null || value == "") {
    alert(msg);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

//Move this function to the L14O2localStorage.js and 
//14O2noLocalStorage.js files.
//function saveTodoItem(todoItem) {
//    if (localStorage) {
//        var key = "todo" + todoItem.id;
//        var item = JSON.stringify(todoItem);
//        localStorage.setItem(key, item);
//    }
//    else {
//        console.log("Error: you don't have localStorage!");
//    }
//}

function updateDone(e) {
 var span = e.target;
 var id = span.parentElement.id;
 var item;
  for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
    if (todos[i].id == id) {
        item = todos[i];
        break;
    }
 }
 if (item.done == false) {
    item.done = true;
    span.setAttribute("class", "done");
    span.innerHTML = "&nbsp;&#10004;&nbsp;";
 }
 else if (item.done == true) {
    item.done = false;
    span.setAttribute("class", "notDone");
    span.innerHTML = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
 }
  var itemJson = JSON.stringify(item);
  var key = "todo" + id;
  localStorage.setItem(key, itemJson);
}

function deleteItem(e) {
  var span = e.target;
  var id = span.parentElement.id;

  // find and remove the item in localStorage
  var key = "todo" + id;
  localStorage.removeItem(key);

  // find and remove the item in the array
  for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
    if (todos[i].id == id) {
        todos.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
  }

// find and remove the item in the page
  var li = e.target.parentElement;
  var ul = document.getElementById("todoList");
  ul.removeChild(li);

//clear map from page
  var map = document.getElementById("map");
  map.innerHTML = "";

// hide search results
  hideSearchResults();
}

// Search
 function searchTodos() {
  // new search, so clear previous results
  clearSearchResultsList();
  // get the text to search for
  var searchTerm = document.getElementById("searchTerm").value;
  var count = 0;
  // check all the todos in the list
  for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
    var todoItem = todos[i];
    // make a regular expression to match the search term, regardless of 
    //case
    var re = new RegExp(searchTerm, "i");
    // try matching the expression with the task and the who from the to 
    //do item
    if (todoItem.task.match(re) || todoItem.who.match(re)) {
        // if we find a match, add the to do item to the search results
        addSearchResultToPage(todoItem);
        // keep a count of the number of items we match
        count++;
    }
  }
  // if we don't match any items, display "no results" 
  if (count == 0) {
      var ul = document.getElementById("searchResultsList");
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerHTML = "No results!";
      ul.appendChild(li);
  }
  // show the search results
  showSearchResults();
}

// add a search result to the search results list in the page
function addSearchResultToPage(todoItem) {
  var ul = document.getElementById("searchResultsList");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML =
    todoItem.who + " needs to " + todoItem.task + " by " +  
      todoItem.dueDate;
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

// clear the previous search results 
function clearSearchResultsList() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("searchResultsList");
  while (ul.firstChild) {
    ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
  }
}

function hideSearchResults() {
  var div = document.getElementById("searchResults");
  div.style.display = "none";
  clearSearchResultsList();
}

function showSearchResults() {
  var div = document.getElementById("searchResults");
  div.style.display = "block";
  document.forms[0].reset();
} 

function checkDate(date) {
  if (isValidDate(date) == false) {
  return false;
  }
  console.log(date + " is a valid date");   
  return true;
}

function isValidDate(date) {
// Checks for the following valid date format of mm/dd/yyyy
// mm/dd/yyyy and yyyy/mm/dd

  var regEx1 = /^(\d{2,2})(\/)(\d{2,2})\2(\d{4}|\d{4})$/;
 // var regEx2 = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/;
 //if (date != "" && date.match(regEx1) && date.match(regEx2) )
 if (date != "" && date.match(regEx1)) {
  alert("Invalid Date Format: " + date);
  return false;
 }
 return true;  
}

//Function to calculate the number of days until an item is either due
//or overdue.
function calculateDays(date) {
 var today = new Date();
 var d1 = today.getTime();
 var dateIn = new Date(date);
 var d2 = dateIn.getTime();
 var year = today.getFullYear();
 var month = today.getMonth()+1;
 var day = today.getDate();
 var time = today.getTime();

 var total = parseInt((d1-d2)/(24*3600*1000));
 console.log("Total: " + total); 
 return total; 
}
```

The geolocation JavaScript File:

```
 //If geolocation is found by Modernizr the map where the to do item is 
 //to be completed will be displayed in the mapDiv on the page.
 function findLocation(lat, lon) {
  console.log("In Geolocation");
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation);
 }

function displayLocation(position) {
  var map = null;

  latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  longitude = position.coords.longitude;

  lat = latitude;
  lon = longitude;

  console.log("Lat: " + lat + " Lon: " + lon);

  if (!map) {
    showMap(latitude, longitude);
  } 
  addMarker(latitude, longitude);
  return(lat, lon); 
}

function showMap(lat, long) {
  var googleLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: googleLatLong,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map");
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);
  map.panTo(googleLatLong);
}

function addMarker(lat, long) {
  var googleLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
  var markerOptions = {
    position: googleLatLong,
    map: map,
    title: "Task Location"
 }
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
}
```

noGeolocation JavaScript File:

```
//If geolocation is not found by Modernizr a message will be displayed 
//in the console and on the page showing that geolocation is not enabled.
function findLocation() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map");
  mapDiv.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not enabled on this browser.";
  console.log("Geolocation is not enabled on this browser.");
}
```

localStorage JavaScript File:

```
//If localStorage is found by Modernizr the to do item will be stored in 
//localStorage and message displayed in the console.
function saveToDoItem(todoItem) {
  var key = "todo" + todoItem.id;
  var item = JSON.stringify(todoItem);
  localStorage.setItem(key, item);
  console.log("Item: " + key + ", " + item + " stored in local storage");
}
```

noLocalStorage JavaScript File:

```
//If localStorage is found by Modernizr the to do item will be stored in 
//localStorage and message displayed in the console.
function saveToDoItem(todoItem) {
  var key = "todo" + todoItem.id;
  var item = JSON.stringify(todoItem);
  localStorage.setItem(key, item);
  console.log("Item: " + key + ", " + item + " stored in local storage");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to remove the code for `findlocation()` from your `toDo` JavaScript file. Call the `findlocation()` in the `getFormData` function.

Your `createNewTodo()` code should start with:

```
function createNewTodo(todoItem) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute("id", todoItem.id);
    var spanTodo = document.createElement("span");
    var daysUntilDue = calcDaysLeft(todoItem.dueDate);
    spanTodo.innerHTML = CallTodoStr(todoItem, daysUntilDue);
}
```

Finally, you should have a code like this in your find Geolocation file:

```
function CallTodoStr(todoItem, daysUntilDue) {
    var todoStr = "(" + todoItem.latitude + ", " + todoItem.longitude
                  + ") " + todoItem.who + " needs to " + todoItem.task
                  + " by " + todoItem.dueDate + "  " + daysUntilDue;
    return todoStr;
}
```